# how to bring an instance from one subnet to the other which is having a docker containers running in that instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ami

I have tried it by creating an AMI and then tried to launching an instance in the private subnet, but I don't see any containers inside the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that :

1. Docker daemon is running  ( check how to start it at the boot time, For example: `systemd`, `chckconfig` ... )
2. Make sure your containers were started on the original instance with `--restart=always`  or again use something to start them ( cron / systemd ... )